# rewrite engine is removing slashes from my urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have looked everywhere and spent hours trying to get this working, but I have been unsuccessful.  I could really use some help.

I am not an expert with apache but I have an old URL and am trying to redirect all my old pages to my new URL. My old URL is:

www.bc-mortgage-brokers.ca

My new URL is

http://bc-mortgage-broker.ca

The home page redirects correctly, but it is the only one to do so.  For example, if I type:

www.bc-mortgage-brokers.ca/16/

into my browswer, it removes the slashes and then fails to redirect.  I will get this url instead:

bc-mortgage-broker.ca16

in my .htaccess file, I have the entry for this particular one as:

```
redirect 301 /16/ http://bc-mortgage-broker.ca/16/
```

My header for the file is currently:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

I am creating the file in textmate.

When I look at the error logs, I read:

RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(16(?:/.*)?)$ http://bc-mortgage-broker.ca/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That did it.  My hosting provider could not answer this question for me even.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry I am stuck again.  I see that that rewrite rule only applied to one page.  However, I have about 130 pages to redirect, some of them with the same canonical name, some with a different name. With the redirect command, is there a way I can just do the redirect without the redirect removing the / symbol? I am having a difficult time understanding the syntax and why it is needed to do it that way when there are 100 pages out there and lots of documentation on the Redirect command.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I got the solution using the RewriteMatch rule instead of the rewrite rule and it works well.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.